# Sharethis plugin not working with https://

Tags: javascript, php, ssl, sharethis

I have changed my site domain from `http://` to `https://` and I have added sharethis plugin in my site.

It was working fine with `http://` but now no buttons of share this displaying when I try to access my site using `https://`.

The following is the url of my site:

https://www.placementbooster.ch/

I have changed `http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js` to `https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js` and `http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js` to `https://s.sharethis.com/loader.js`.

But still it is showing error:

> ReferenceError: sharethis is not defined

Answer (score 10):

Adapted from the docs:

https://support.sharethis.com/hc/en-us/articles/217916188-Moving-from-HTTP-to-HTTPS-SSL-Support

**Regular ShareThis Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({
    publisher:'12345',
});
</script>
```

**Secure ShareThis Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ss.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({
    publisher:'12345',
});
</script>
```

I'm using this code ant it is loading correctly without any mixed-content issues

Comment: Whose idea what it to change the URL like this?! Thanks for the verbose answer.

Comment: what file is this supposed to be in? I'm trying it in the `share-this/sharethis.php`, but it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 6):

I was getting "stLight" is not defined and found a [blog post](https://support.sharethis.com/hc/en-us/articles/217916188-Moving-from-HTTP-to-HTTPS-SSL-Support) about moving to HTTPS. It basically says change "http://w" to "https://ws" and following it solved that problem.  The post does have a link with "https://ss" in it.  Perhaps you need to change "https://s" to "https://ss"?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ss.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options({
    publisher:'12345',
});
</script>
```

This has solved our issue.